# Silly fstab question

Tags: fstab

I'm trying to automatically mount a NAS drive on start. The command I'm using to manually mount it is:

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.88:/NAS /media/nas
```

This works fine. This is what I'm putting in my fstab file which isn't working:

```
//192.168.1.57/nas /media/nas nas _netdev,auto 0 0
```

No doubt a basic error but my googling has failed me. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manual mount command NFS server IP and one you mentioned as fstab entry seems different. Assuming source IP is 192.168.1.88, try below:

```
192.168.1.88:/NAS    /media/nas    nfs    defaults    0 0
```

Comment: Might freeze the loading phase because the the `auto` flag, also, `0 0` at the end is not recommended for remote FS.

Comment: @Yaron changed it to defaults since I earlier copied the mount options from OP. _netdev can still be used though.